# Rails view segment dependent on udpated_at/created_at time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I can do this in a view to add labels to news stories:

```
<% if article.urgency == 'majorbreaking' && article.updated_at.today? %>
  <span class="breaking">
…
```

It works out of the box with 'today', but how do I do the same thing with (say) "last six hours" (in a view, I know how to to it with scopes and controllers to select the articles, but this is after selection, just for the view).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is after selection, we can simply use like this:

```
article.updated_at >= 6.hours.ago
```

Simple & pretty

Comment: Thank you Hieu, that works. That was the bit I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

You can minimize the hard-coded logic that your view is processing and potential DRY up your code (if in fact you want to process multiple time spans) by creating a method in your article model. For example:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def recent?(hours_ago=24)
    created_at >= hours_ago.hours.ago
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

For within the last day:

```
<% if article.urgency == 'majorbreaking' && article.recent? %>
  <span class="breaking">
```

For within the last 6 hours:

```
<% if article.urgency == 'majorbreaking' && article.recent?(6) %>
  <span class="breaking">
```

Comment: I think it has to be `hours_ago.ago`

Comment: Yes!  Thanks... fixing now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace that `at_today` with the last 6 hours use:

```
<% if article.urgency == 'majorbreaking' && article.updated_at > (DateTime.now - 6.hours) %>
  <span class="breaking">
…
```

check out time helpers

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

Comment: I will have a read of those again. I was trying before but it didn't click. Thanks.